# Adding a running count of distinct values in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, window-functions

I have a table that records which hardware was used for a given run (job / batch) on a tool. Vastly simplified, the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE hardware (
  `run_name` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `hardware_used` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`run_name`)
);
```

```
run_name   hardware_used
pk123          h1
pk124          h1
pk125          h2
pk126          h2
pk127          h2
pk128          h3
pk129          h1
```

I want to get a running count of how many times each hardware has been used:

```
run_name   hardware_used   times_used
pk123          h1              1
pk124          h1              2
pk125          h2              1
pk126          h2              2
pk127          h2              3
pk128          h3              1
pk129          h1              3
```

In lexicographical order of `run_name`, create a running tally of how many times a given `hardware_used` has been seen.

In SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and MySQL 8, I think it could be done using Window Functions. Eg: the using SQL Server's OVER clause and Partitions, but I'm stuck with using **MySQL 5.7**.

Is something like this possible to generate in pure SQL?

Comment: @Akina I'm not sure I follow. The table with `run_name`, `hardware_used` and `times_used` is exactly the result I'm looking for. What part are you claiming does not match fully?

Comment: "where is times_used = 3 for hardware_used = 1?"   Ah, yes that's a typo. The final row should have times_used=3, not times_used=4. Sorry about that. I've updated the Q to fix that and also added a note about ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.run_name, hardware_used, COUNT(*) times_used
FROM hardware t1
JOIN hardware t2 USING (hardware_used)
WHERE t1.run_name >= t2.run_name
GROUP BY t1.run_name, hardware_used
ORDER BY t1.run_name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf9aae19b89ddcd64c6ca9ef6786ea3f)

Comment: Perfect! Very clever joining the table to itself. I normally only do that with self-referential tables - I didn't think to use that same idea here!